# Wordpress giving gibberish and wp-admin gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: migration

I'm transferring my website to a different host. After transffering the database, when I go to the main URL of my site, it gives me half a page of gibberish, like in another encoding. Going to wp-admin gives 500 status error. The logs for the server, nginx, don't give anything, as well as the debug.log from wordpress. What could be the issue?

Comment: You've answered your own question - encoding. How exactly did you migrate your website? Did you ensure that when moving the database, you used the same charsets and collations? Is the new MySQL host the same version as the old one? What about PHP? And the PHP MySQL client library?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be corrupt files. I was migrating things to my computers SD card, then onto the server. Big mistake. Not the first time the SD card would corrupt my files. I've redone it with rsync now, directly from server to server and that fixed the issue.